# Skype Convert Chat ID to Skype Join URL

Tags: skype

would it be possible to convert the skype group chat id to a joinable link for guests via java, or php?

Example:

`19:xxxxxxxxxx@thread.skype => https://join.skype.com/xxxxxxxxx`

I've seen someone do it before, but i have no idea how. if anyone could help it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This is old -- but here's how I do it (disclaimer: skype protocol is subject to change, and this is an unofficial python module for Skype):

Using python, get the skpy module, log in and query the url:

```
from skpy import Skype

username = '<your username>'
password = '<your password>'

sk = Skype(username, password) # connect to Skype

# to go from id to url
chat_id = '<skype chat id>'
ch = sk.chats.chat(chat_id)
join_url = ch.joinUrl

# to go from url to id
join_url = '<skype url to get id>'
chat_id = sk.chats.urlToIds(join_url)
```